# Regex for before & after the decimal...including precision

Tags: javascript, regex

I am horrible at Regular Expression's...and need a Regular Expression that limits before AND after the decimal.

TWO-BY-TWO EXAMPLE:

For instance...

- 22.22  ..should be good
- 22     ..should be good
- .22    ..should be good
- .2     ..should be good
- 222    ..should fail

I need this for a KEYPRESS event...so it must allow periods

And...unfortunately...I cannot use a 3rd party masking tool.

So...

The first 2 must be a number
The third CAN BE a period
The last 2 are optional, but must be a number

Comment: `^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$` (assuming your regex engine supports `\d` and `{x,y}` syntaxes.)

Comment: @wally did you test that first?

Comment: Yes, I tested at https://regex101.com/

Comment: @PrisonerZERO when you say *two-by-two* can you elaborate? Would `2222` or `2222.2222` be ok?

Comment: Please notice the "for instance" requirement in the question...you may have skipped over it

Comment: @PrisonerZERO no, I didn't *skip over it*, you just never elaborated on what **exactly** *two-by-two* means. What about `33.33` or `12.12`?

Comment: 2 to the left (max)...2 to the right (max)...and thanks for the help

Comment: @PrisonerZERO 2 to the left and two to the right max of which digits? Do both sides need to be composed of the same number, digits, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166254/discussion-between-prisoner-zero-and-ctwheels).

Comment: Max, or exactly? Your examples show exactly. Does `1.2` match? How about just `.4`?

Comment: You calim the first two must be a number yet .22 does nit start with a number. So how can the first two be a number?

Comment: The regex given by @wally shoul perfectly work in the examples given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$`

Explanation:

```
^         start of string
\d        numerical digit (use [0-9] if not supported)
{0,2}     previous (numerical digit) is 0, 1 or 2 in length
(         group (made optional by the trailing ?)
  \.        "decimal place" (dot)
  {1,2}     1 or 2 in length
)?        (end of the group, made optional by the ?)
$         end of string
```

Matches:

```
22.22
22
2.22
2.2
22.2
22
.22
```

**Update:**  OP requests that `22.` be allowed too.  This is easily achieved by making all the "digits after the decimal place" optional too:

`^\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?$`  (allowing `.` as well, or...)

`^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?|\d{1,2}\.)$` (not allowing `.` on its own.)

Comment: Hi wally...some minor trouble still.  When I try to type-in "11."...the period fails.  Any thoughts

Comment: Yes, the regex doesn't allow for that ;-)  (Your question didn't specify whether that should/shouldn't be allowed.  I assumed not.)
You can modify it thusly: `^\d{0,2}(\.\d{0,2})?$`

Comment: @wally that'll match `.`

Comment: Yes it will.  (Would be humanly interpreted as `0.0` I guess?)  If you want **only** digits with a decimal place:  `^(\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?|\d{1,2}\.)$` - which could probably be code-golf'd to shorter still :-)

Answer (score 2):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/uX67zo/2)

```
^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})` Match either of the following options

  - `\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?`

    - `\d{1,2}` Match a digit once or twice
    - `(?:\.\d{0,2})?` Optionally match the following

      - `\.` Match the dot `.` character literally
      - `\d{0,2}` Match zero to two digits
  - `\.\d{1,2}`

    - `\.` Match the dot `.` character literally
    - `\d{1,2}` Match a digit once or twice
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

```js
var r = /^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$/
var a = [
  1.11, 1.1, .11, 11., 11, 11.11, //good
  111, 11.111, 111.1, 1111 //bad
]

a.forEach(function(n) {
  if(r.test('' + n)) {
    console.log(n)
  }
})
```